# Material-UI app bar comes with a margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I used  [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) 's AppBar component and it works well, but comes with a margin, anyone got a workaround. I need to get rid of the margin.

Comment: IF anyone else runs into this issue, I'd recommend checking out this issue on Github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7466

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always specify custom styles on a *material-ui* component by passing it the `style` property like so:

```
<AppBar style={{ margin: 0 }}/>
```

That will override the default root element style. If the property you're willing to change is on a children component, you'll have to set it using CSS, if there is no specific property *material-ui* exposes you.

---

Removing the margin on the body would also fix your problem

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Although you should usually use a CSS reset to avoid getting errors like these by integrating the following CSS snippet:

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, but my problem was with the body having a margin. Removing margin from body solved it.

Answer (score 27):

Just insert [CssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/api/css-baseline/) tag before any element whose default margins you want to remove. Like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from "./Components/Main";
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
// or
// import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <CssBaseline/>
          //Any element below this will not have the default margin
          <Main/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/#main-content

Answer (score 26):

If you use default React Web template to create the project, you can edit the `index.html` file in `public` folder, add below style in body:

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
...
</body>
```

Or add it in you css file like below:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 5):

You can use Css Baseline from Material-ui  (https://material-ui-next.com/style/css-baseline/)

```
import React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

function MyApp() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* The rest of your application */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: CssBaseline component to kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/#main-content

Answer (score 2):

In material-ui 4.11.1 you can change position param from '**static**' to '**abolute**'
[material-ui AppBarr API](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/)

```
<AppBar position='absolute' color='primary'>
<Toolbar>{/*code here*/}</Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

for now i don´t know how much this will affect the nav bar behavior, but it will solve this anoying by-default feature

Answer (score 1):

The trick {{ margin }}  did not work for me , so i tried using this css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ .

Works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still need the answer,
<AppBar position="absolute"

Below are other properties:
"absolute","fixed","relative","static","sticky"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MUI +v5 you can use the `disableGutters` prop directly:

```
<Appbar disableGutters />
```

Comment: Should be on the `Toolbar` not the `AppBar` https://mui.com/material-ui/api/toolbar/

Comment: It removes the top padding, but the `AppBar` still has the left and right padding.

Answer (score -1):

Fix your App bar on top left like this

```
 <AppBar
          position="static"
          color="inherit"
          style={{ position: 'fixed', top: 0 , left : 0,  margin: 0}}
        >
```